# Проблемы с относительным путем при запуске jar файла (java -jar <name>.jar)

Tags: java, jar, path

Есть строка, которая содержит путь и используется далее в методах:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Pavel\\IdeaProjects\\CoursApp\\src\\main\\resources\\environment.properties";
```

При подобной записи пути все работает хорошо, программа отрабатывает и при запуске с помощью простой конфигурации intelij idea и при запуске через java -jar .jar
Проблема в том, что такой вариант будет работать только на моем компьютере из-за абсолютного пути.

Мне нужно, чтобы путь задавался так:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH = "src/main/resources/environment.properties";
```

Либо же так:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH = "./src/main/resources/environment.properties";
```

НО! при попытке запуска с таким заданием пути программа работает нормально, только если запускать через intelij idea
При попытке запустить файл через java -jar, который генерит maven в папке target: [image], компилятор не находит файл по данном пути

Интересно, что если закинуть cours.jar в основной проект и попытаться запустить его отуда, то все работает
Ощущение, что я что-то в корне неправильно понимаю, подскажите, пожалуйста

Полная структура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вашем вопросе не описана чётка структура проекта. Сделайте скриншот полной структуры проекта, нахождения вашего jar файла и файла environment.properties. Так вопрос будет намного понятнее.

Comment: По идее вам вообще не надо падать в src/main поскольку у вас фал лежит в ресурсах

Comment: прошу прощения за долго отсутствие, но вопрос еще актуален, добавил структуру проекта

Comment: @PerfectVoyage почему это?